# Android show all email applications in a chooser without composing a new email

Tags: android

In my application I wish to send a server-side authentication email. I'd like to open a chooser that shows every email application available on the device.

I can do this with the following lines code:

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
 emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
```

**Problem 1:** This will always compose an empty message, all I want to do is display every email application so that the user will be directed to their desired inbox.

Upon further research I found that I can open the email application (without composing a new message) by adding a category type:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
emailIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
```

**Problem 2:** This solution will only show the *default* email application only (testing on a Samsung device means that only the 'Email' app is shown not third party apps such as Gmail, Outlook etc). This is not ideal as I'd like to offer the user the ability to open their email client of choice.

Most resources online show how to send an email via your own application however I have not found any way to show the user every email app but **NOT** compose a new email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @jayeffkay I ended up creating a whitelist of popular email client package names then creating a chooser if they were installed. Not ideal for users with alternative email clients but it seemed to be the simplest option

Comment: Could you share code/ ideas of how to implement such a feature?

Answer (score 4):

Your `CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL` is [documented to specifically be **not** used the way that you are using it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL). It is [for `makeMainSelectorActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#makeMainSelectorActivity%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which should in theory give you what you want. Try:

```
Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
    Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
```

and see if that gives you what you want.

> I'd like to open a chooser that shows every email application available on the device.

Bear in mind that the user may be using none of these. They might use Web mail in a browser. They might not access email on their mobile device. They might not use email. They might think that email is something for old people. And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Commonsware. using makeMainSelectoyActivity() will directly open the default email application without showing the choose. I completely agree that this is a solution that will not cover all use cases but we feel that asking the user to 'check your inbox' without giving them an option to do so is a bit lazy. Thanks